# Can someone provide a vimeo simple api working example (using the standard embed object, not froogaloop)?

Tags: javascript, api, events, vimeo, ready

Vimeo docs are quite poor. I cannot get the simple api ready event fired.
I studied the docs, but their not clear. I posted in forums, but answers are not clear.
If I use a normal embed tag (in this case I must do it), it should automatically fire the ready event and listen to a default vimeo_player_loaded() function. It doesn't. Or at least it doesn't seem to do that.

About the ready event, the docs clearly state:

"Fired automatically when the player is ready to accept commands. Do not try to add listeners or call functions before receiving this event. When using the Flash Embed Code, the player will attempt to call vimeo_player_loaded()."

So????

And by the way, my code (video correcly embedded but ready callback doesn't get executed):

```
<script>
function vimeo_player_loaded(id){
//doesn't log anything because ready event seems to not fire
console.log(document.getElementById(id).api_play);
}
</script>

<object width="320" height="160">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="flashvars" value="api=1" />
<param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php echo $vimeo_id ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" />
<embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php echo $vimeo_id ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" FlashVars="api=1" width="320" height="160"></embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally did. So I want to share:

```
<div style="width:320px; height:180px" id="flashbox-30861939"></div>
<script>
     //vimeo_player_loaded gets automatically called my the vimeo player
     //when it is ready
     function vimeo_player_loaded(id){
         //id is automatically passed
         var swfobj = document.getElementById(id);
         swfobj.api_play();//it works!!!
     }

     var swf = swfobject.embedSWF("http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=30861939&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0", "flashbox-30861939", "320", "180", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", { api:1, player_id:"flashbox-30861939" }, { allowfullscreen:true, allowscriptaccess:'always' });
</script>
```

So, in the end I used the swfobject (please include the swfobject.js in page before caling the code above..).

One should be quite carefull in passing the right ids. Also, pay attention to the flash vars:

```
{ api:1, player_id:"flashbox-30861939" }
```

and to the params:

```
{ allowfullscreen:true, allowscriptaccess:'always' }
```

Hope it helps.
By the way, of course, it's not mandatory to call swfobject.embedSWF AFTER the id. You can do it in the head of the doc as always. I do it there only due to some requirements of my app.

Comment: Thanks for this post. I was able to build this working IE7 Vimeo api code (http://jsfiddle.net/doub1ejack/XXdZ3/) using your post and a couple others (http://jaimonblog.appspot.com/vimeo/index.html and http://derhess.de/vimeoTest/test.html).

Answer (score 1):

Also, when using Moogaloop together with JQuery (and I guess Mootools), make sure the `vimeo_video_loaded()` method is *outside* of the `document.ready()` part of the script, otherwise it will just not be called.